# Automatic Publish of after Build on TFS Build Server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I use the following code example to get access to builds that have been marked as released.  I'd like to be able to automate the copy of the actual setup files to my web server for download.  I also need to update information such as version number etc. in my CRM.

```
    Dim tfsUri As Uri
    tfsUri = New Uri("http://tfsServer:8080/tfs")
    Dim TeamProj As New TfsTeamProjectCollection(New Uri("http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/Software"))
    Dim buildServer As IBuildServer = DirectCast(TeamProj.GetService(GetType(IBuildServer)), IBuildServer)
    Dim oBuilds As IBuildQueryResult
    Dim oBuildDefSpec As IBuildDetailSpec
    oBuildDefSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec("Main Project")
    oBuildDefSpec.MinChangedTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -20, Now)
    oBuildDefSpec.Quality = "Released"
    oBuilds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(oBuildDefSpec)

    For Each oBuild As IBuildDetail In oBuilds.Builds
        Console.WriteLine(oBuild.DropLocation)
    Next
```

oBuild.DropLocation returns the following
"\DropServer\Builds\SoftwareName v2.03.03\SoftwareName QA v2.03.03_V2.03.03.6"

The installer is actually located as shown below
"\DropServer\Builds\SoftwareName v2.03.03\SoftwareName QA v2.03.03_V2.03.03.6\TFSProjectName\Install\DiskImages\DISK1\Software Setup Name.exe"

Assuming that Install\DiskImages\Disk1" are always constant, I would like to be able to get the TFSProjectName and the actual "Software Setup Name.exe" text from TFS.

Is there a way, once I've programmatically accessed the build definition, to then access the project it came from and get the actual software version, the setup project output name etc?  If there is I hope to use this information to automatically finish the path needed to pickup the installer and get the other info needed to update my CRM.

Comment: Does the name "Software Setup Name.exe" always change?

Comment: It can change from time to time based on what the developer assigns in the setup project.  I just don't know how to get to the setup project in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MSBuild argument `/target:publish` to make MSBuild create the ClickOnce publish folder.

Here is a blog which is talking about how to edit the XAML build definition to build and publish a ClickOnce application:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2015/09/15/build-and-publish-a-clickonce-app-using-team-build-vso.aspx